# Jquery: animate .outerWidth()?

Tags: jquery, width, toggle, jquery-animate, outer-join

When animating a width toggle, it's not animating the padding, so i looked into .outerWidth() but i'm not exactly sure how to implement this...

```
$('#shareheart').click(function(){
    $('.share-text').animate({outerWidth: 'toggle'}, 2000)
})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Animate only works on css properties. Im not sure what the `toggle` key word does but i assume its shortand for alternating `hide`/`show` keyword. you could try:

```
$('#shareheart').click(function(){
    $('.share-text').animate({
      width: 'toggle', 
     'padding-left': 'toggle', 
     'padding-right': 'toggle'
    }, 2000);
});
```

But im not sure how toggle will work with the padding...

Comment: perfect, you deserve some frosted flakes, they're grrrrrreat!