# jQuery: animate outerWidth

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-animate

Related to: [Jquery: animate .outerWidth()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965092/jquery-animate-outerwidth)

Assuming, `wrap` is the parent element in `body`.

The following sets the width to the maximum width:
    `$('#wrap').outerWidth($(window).width());`

However, when trying to animate this, the dimensions extend beyond the document, most likely because of paddings and scrollbars:
    `$('#wrap').animate( {width: $(window).width()}, 'slow');`

Answer (score 1):

```
   var wrap = $('#wrap');

   $('#fooID')
      .stop(true,true)
      .animate({
                   width: (
                             $(window).width()
                                - parseFloat(wrap.css('padding-right'))
                                - parseFloat(wrap.css('padding-left'))
                                - parseFloat(wrap.css('border-right-width'))
                                - parseFloat(wrap.css('border-left-width'))
                          )
               }
               , 'slow'
       );
```

Any better way?