# Animate width to zero including padding of a DIV

Tags: jquery, css

I'm very new to jQuery and CSS, and I'm trying to animate two DIVs of class .iDoElement with the following jQuery code:

```
$( '.iDoElement' ).each(function () {
        var randomDelay = Math.floor(Math.random() * 600);          
        $(this).delay(randomDelay).animate ({width:0}, 1000); 
    });
```

...but both divs have padding-right and padding-left defined, this means that they're not going to width 0 (I'm reading on the web that the width of a div affect its content and ignores the padding).

How to solve it? Is animatind padding-left and padding-right to zero too the only solution?

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965092/jquery-animate-outerwidth

Comment: Look at this: http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/

Comment: @BillyMoat thanks, but how can I use the outerWitdh(true) technique in the animate block? As I said i'm very new to jQuery :)

Comment: why don't you just add your padding to the animate: animate ({width:0, padding:0}, 1000)

Comment: @Pete I'm doing it, I'm just curious to know if there is any other option available.... I'm learning and I want to be sure

Comment: you could remove the padding and add it to the width, and animate just the width (width = outerwidth, padding = 0) or you could nest a div and move the padding to that one, and animate the outer one.

Comment: you could add the style `box-sizing:border-box` then it will ignore the padding but then this will only work in newer browsers or wrap the div in another div and then just animate that one

Comment: @Sr.Richie - How about this?: http://jsfiddle.net/G6bTD/

Comment: more like this: http://jsfiddle.net/G6bTD/3 anyway animating the padding as well looks like the cleanest solution to me

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/G6bTD/

```
$('.iDoElement').each(function () {
    var randomDelay = Math.floor(Math.random() * 600);
    $(this).delay(randomDelay).animate({width:'toggle'}, 1000); 
});
```

Comment: @DavidFregoli - Is my fiddle not working for you?

Comment: It shrinks to a certain width (the padding values) and then disappears. The goal would be to make it animate to 0

Comment: Strange, I've tested it in Firefox and Chrome and it animates to zero for me. Not sure why it's only animating down to the padding value then disappearing for you.